# How can you delete Contacts that don't have any recent Cases using Bulk Deletion Jobs?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm trying to figure out the criteria for a Bulk Deletion Job in Dynamics 365 to enforce GDPR.

Essentially, I need to delete Contact records that haven't been used for more than 13 months.

The main part of the Criteria I've been using is where 'Modified On is Older Than 13 months'.

The problem with this is that the 'Modified On' field only updates when you change the details of the Contact record.
For example, a Contact might've been created in 2019 and the details have remained the same since then - therefore the Modified On date is 2019. However, this Contact only just emailed us last week and so their Contact is still in use but this isn't reflected in the Modified On date.

The criteria I have come up with to try and get around this is as follows:
[image]

Unfortunately, this is still returning Contacts that don't match the criteria I need.

Is it possible to get this criteria using the advanced find functionality, or will it require something external?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the ***usual recommendation is not to delete the records*** or you'll lose historic data, and you will end up with several records in the system with broken relationships.

If you already backed-up historic data or it does not have any value to the business, unless someone can correct me, I think what you are trying to do won't work with advance find. This is because of the limitation in advanced find with related entities and the fact the we cannot add conditions to the "Does not contain data" relationship option.

Your criteria is not giving the results you expect because it is requesting the following (assuming you have selected the Contact table in advanced find):

> Select Contacts whose modifiedOn date is older than 13 months and that
> they are linked as the customer of a case whose modifiedOn date is
> older than 13 months and these cases have a related email whose
> modiedOn date is older than 13 months

So, what you are retrieving are old Contacts that had a at least one Case some time ago, and not Contacts with no recent activity (A Contact can have an old Case, but may/may not have a recent one).

Another thing to consider is that you are using the "Customer" column [Cases(Customer)] from the Case table. Depending on how your organizations is handling this column and since the Customer column can hold Accounts or Contacts, you might want to use "primarycontactid" [Cases(Contact)] or another custom column (I've seen some designs were a custom column is used to track the Contact).

Last year I had a request for an organization to automatically merge thousands of contacts following some rules. What I ended up doing was a Console Application and one of the steps was to validate if the Contacts had any interactions (Leads, Opportunities, Cases and Activities) and count them, this way when the merge was performed I chose the Contact with more related records as the main Contact. So a similar approach could be use in your scenario.

You can create an efficient query with QueryExpressions, but if you are not used to them you can use this FetchXML in the console Application

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="incident" from="primarycontactid" to="contactid" link-type="outer" alias="case">
      <attribute name="incidentid" />
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-months" value="13" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It will give you a list of Contacts and if they had a Case that was modified in the last 13 months, you'll get a GUID in the `case.incidentid` column, if you have a null value in `case.incidentid`, it means that there are no recent Cases and should be deleted.

Keep in mind that :

1. You might need to update the FetchXML to your needs.
2. You'll need to handle paging on the query results if there are more than 5,000 Contacts.
3. Depending on the number of Contacts in the system you'll want to create different batches to process them because it can take a while to complete.
4. It would be a good idea to create a report to validate the Contacts before deleting them.